# Is this a good way to parse a ftp url scheme?

Tags: java, parsing, url

I write a small java tool and a at the beginning I have to parse a url. I would like to know, what you are thinking about my solution and if there is a better way?
Here are some examples:

> aaa://username:password@server:port/dir/
>
> aaa://server:port/dir/
>
> aaa://server:port

Every kind of String is possible, if the user is not carefully. So it is possible, that my function get such a string

> aaa://username:pass

too. But the string always starts witch aaa://.

Here is my code:

url = url.replaceFirst("aaa://", "");

```
String params[] = url.split("@");
if(params[0].compareTo("") != 0) {
    String paramsfst[] = params[0].split(":");
    if(params.length == 1) {
        if(paramsfst.length >= 1) {
            this.server = parsePort(paramsfst[0]);
            if(paramsfst.length == 2) {
                this.port = parsePort(paramsfst[1]);
            }
        }               
    } else {
        String paramssec[] = params[1].split(":");
        if(paramssec.length >= 1) {
            this.server = parsePort(paramssec[0]);
            if(paramssec.length == 2) {
                this.port = parsePort(paramssec[1]);
            }
        }
        if(paramsfst.length == 2) {
            this.username = paramsfst[0];
            this.password = paramsfst[1];   
        }
    }
    if(url.contains("/")) {
        this.path = url.substring(url.indexOf("/"), url.length() -1);   
    }

private String parsePort(String port) {
    int i = port.indexOf("/");
    if(i == -1) {
        return port;
    }
    return port.substring(0, i);
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: If this isn't about *how* to parse an URL, this should go to codereview.

Comment: I have written a library that can help you out solving this: https://github.com/smola/galimatias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at the [**URL class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)?

See here [**for an example**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html).

Comment: Looks interesting. Doesn’t know that there are methods to query a URL object. I will have a look tomorrow at the URL class. Now I have to sleep. It’s too late to work.

Comment: I have some problems with the URL class. I cannot use it, because I don’t use a standard scheme at the beginning and the URL class check if java is able to open a connection. I tried URI, but here I got some Problems with the path. My path could contain spaces. Any idea? I will have also a look at regex,

Answer (score 0):

Personally, that looks like a lot of code for my taste.  I think you can nail it a lot more compactly using `regex`, when you define your pattern and how to chop it in different capture groups all in one line, then read your group values later into vars and done deal.  I gotta run now, maybe I can come up with code later but just look under `java regex`, there is a fairly decent tutorial by Oracle.

Comment: Good idea, I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are looking for [java.net.URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html):**

```
final String destination = "ftp://anonymous@localhost:21/inbox?password=secret"

final URI uri = new URI(destination);

String host = uri.getHost(); //localhost
final int port = uri.getPort(); //21
final String directoryPath = uri.getPath();  //inbox
String username = uri.getUserInfo(); //anonymous

//The password can exist as a query parameter or as part of the user info
final List<NameValuePair> queryParams = URLEncodedUtils.parse(uri, "UTF-8");
final Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap();
queryParams.forEach((param) -> { paramsMap.put(param.getName(), param.getValue()); });

String password = null;
if (paramsMap.containsKey("password"))
{
    password = paramsMap.get("password"); //secret
}
else if ((username != null) && username.contains(":"))
{
    password = username.split(":")[1];
    username = username.split(":")[0];
}
```